# Validating model with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, nsregularexpression

Hi I am using a validation like below to ensure I am just working on a csv file.

```
 [RegularExpression(@"(csv)|(CSV)")]
 public string AttachmentFileName { get; set; }
```

After form submit model returns a value

```
AttachmentFileName = "UserMapping.csv"
```

However I am still getting validation error as:

> The field AttachmentFileName must match the regular expression '(csv)|(CSV)'.

Where I am doing error? I tested my expression on website, there it seems to work alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fix it by matching the whole string ([RegularExpressionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) requires a full string match):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^.*[.][cC][sS][vV]$")]
public string AttachmentFileName { get; set; }
```

The `^.*[.][cC][sS][vV]$` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `[.]` - a dot
- `[cC][sS][vV]` - `csv` (case insensitive)
- `$`  - end of string.